# Creating Fixed Width files from strings

Tags: file-io, vbscript

I have searched high and low on the internet and I can't find a straight answer to this !
I have a file that has approx 100,000 characters in one long line.

I need to read this file in and write it out again in its entirety, in lines 102 character long ending with VbCrLf. There are no delimiters.

I thought there were a number of ways to tackle issues like this in VB Script... but 
apparently not !

Can anyone please provide me with a pointer ?

Answer (score 1):

Here's something (off the top of my head - untested!) that should get you started.

```
Const ForReading = 1
Const ForWriting = 2
Dim sNewLine

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set tsIn = fso.OpenTextFile("OldFile.txt", ForReading)  ' Your input file
Set tsOut = fso.OpenTextFile("NewFile.txt", ForWriting) ' New (output) file

While Not tsIn.AtEndOfStream              ' While there is still text
  sNewLine = tsIn.Read(102)               ' Read 120 characters
  tsOut.Write sNewLine & vbCrLf         ' Write out to new file + CR/LF
Wend                                    ' Loop to repeat

tsIn.Close
tsOut.Close
```

Answer (score 0):

I won't cover the reading of files, since that is stuff you can find everywhere. And since it's been years I've coded in vb or vbscript, I hope that .net code will suffice.

pseudo: read line from file, put it in for example a string (performance issues anyone?).
A simple algorithm would be and this might have performance issues (multithreading, parallel could be a solution):

```
Public Sub foo()
    Dim strLine As String = "foo²"
    Dim strLines As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)
    Dim nrChars = strLine.ToCharArray.Count
    Dim iterations = nrChars / 102

    For i As Integer = 0 To iterations - 1
        strLines.Add(strLine.Substring(0, 102))
        strLine = strLine.Substring(103)
    Next

    'save it to file
End Sub
```